# SOSEX mdt command wrong output

Tags: c#, windbg, crash-dumps, sos, sosex

I found quite strange issue with [**sosex**](http://www.stevestechspot.com/SOSEXV40NowAvailable.aspx) **!mdt** command.

I was investigating crash memory dump and was checking the value of **System.Web.EtwTrace** class static field using **!mdt** command:

> > **!mdt** System.Web.EtwTrace
> >
> > *[s]**_traceLevel**: int*
> >
> > ...
> >
> > AppDomain '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130489393569613986' (00000000021a2d50): **0x0000000000000000**

I decided to doublecheck the value using [**!DumpClass**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx)  SOS command:

> > **!DumpClass** 000007feec7ddbb8
> >
> > Class Name:      System.Web.EtwTrace
> >
> > ....
> >
> > shared  static    **_traceLevel** **6**

Looks like a bug in SOSEX, has anybody faced same issue ?

Comment: Hi Nick.  First, please make sure you're using the latest version of sosex.  If you are, then report this issue to the email address listed in !sosex.help or !sosexhelp.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your prompt reply. I have downloaded the latest SOSEX, but still an issue persists =\ I have sent a mail as you noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coudn't set up an EtwTrace quickly. It seems to work for my own class at least:

```
0:000> !name2ee EtwTraceDebug EtwTraceDebug.Program
Module:      001d2eac
Assembly:    EtwTraceDebug.exe
Token:       02000002
MethodTable: 001d37fc
EEClass:     001d1260
Name:        EtwTraceDebug.Program

0:000> !dumpclass 001d1260
Class Name:      EtwTraceDebug.Program
mdToken:         02000002
File:            C:\...\EtwTraceDebug.exe
Parent Class:    699b34f8
Module:          001d2eac
Method Table:    001d37fc
Vtable Slots:    4
Total Method Slots:  6
Class Attributes:    100000  
Transparency:        Critical
NumInstanceFields:   0
NumStaticFields:     1
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
69d83aa8  4000001       20         System.Int32  1   static        6 test

0:000> !mdt EtwTraceDebug.Program
EtwTraceDebug.Program
    [s]test: int
        AppDomain 'EtwTraceDebug.exe' (004b8280): 0x00000006
```

However, this may be version specific. Versions used:

```
WinDbg 6.2.9200.16384
SOS 4.0.30319.18444
SOSEX 4.5.0.783 (reported as 4.5.0.0, built Fri Mar 07 16:17:26 2014)
SOSEX 4.5.0.759 (reported as 4.5.0.0, built Mon Dec 02 16:43:57 2013)
SOSEX 4.5.0.721 (reported as 4.5.0.0, built Mon Nov 25 17:49:59 2013)
SOSEX 4.5.0.692 (reported as 4.5.0.0, built Wed Oct 03 16:57:42 2012)
```